# Visual Studio Code breakpoints in typescript

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, source-maps

Using Visual Studio Code, when I set a breakpoint in my .ts file, it is not hit.  (And is not red when I debug).

However, if I set a breakpoint in the compiled JS, then it swaps me to the ts file as I step through the code.  And then any breakpoints in my .ts file start working.

**Is there a way to get .ts file breakpoints to just work (without having to first set one in my compiled .js file?**

NOTE: I looked at this question: [Setting breakpoints in Typescript Jasmine tests with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728095/setting-breakpoints-in-typescript-jasmine-tests-with-visual-studio-code) and it is exactly my issue.  However the answer for that question was to upgrade to VS Code 0.10.9 and Typescript 1.8.2.  I am on VS Code 1.8.1 and Typescript 2.1.4.

Comment: Did you enable `sourceMap` on tsconfig.json?

Comment: @BrunoLM - Yes.  And they seem to be working to some degree.  Or else the breakpoint I put the JavaScript file would not be able to swap me back to the Typescript file.

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue. I suggest creating a simple project and try to replicate your issue. FYI There's a [' trace: "all" ' option](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/node-debugging) you can add to your launch config (it's in the docs but doesn't show up in the intellisense), which helped me a little. My issue appears to be a bug in vsc regarding TS files in sub-directories. I've raised an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-node-debug/issues/127) for it.

Comment: And after further investigations the issue for me was in the gulp generated source maps. Lots of people having similar issues [as mentioned here](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/191).

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to know exactly what you need to change without seeing the particularities of your setup. That said, here are some ideas for you [and a demo project.](https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/VsCodeTypeScriptBreakpoints) There is also a good conversation [in this GitHub issue.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13499) The following is a minimal TypeScript project setup that works on my machine.

**.vscode/launch.json** Set the `program`, `prelaunchTask`, `outFiles`, and `sourceMaps` properties.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/index.ts",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/**/*.js"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**.vscode/settings.json** Tell Visual Studio Code to use the TypeScript version that we've installed in our `node_modules` instead of using the global installation of TypeScript.

```
{
    "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

**.vscode/tasks.json** Define the `tsc -p .` shell command, which is the `prelaunchTask` that we defined in `launch.json`.

```
{
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."]
}
```

**index.ts**

```
console.log('foo');
console.log('bar'); // a breakpoint here gets hit.
```

**package.json** Install TypeScript locally, to give us more control over the version that we use.

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json** Tell the compiler to generate source maps.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Comment: `isShellCommand` is deprecated. Didn't help me. Breakpoints in the same function are hit, but breakpoints deeper in don't get hit.

Comment: Also, make sure the model you are trying to use is ran and/or compiled by typescript.